# Is there a API from Flex/Flash to list all the UIComponent?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am trying to create an API utility using Adobe AIR where given a component name it should list all it methods, variables, and other properties of that component.

But I could not find an API to list all the UIComponents of Flex/Flash.

is there an API to lookup all the UIComponent or if there is no such API, can anyone tell me how do i lookup the components?

Note: I have tried using flash.utils.describeType() but it is not able to suit my requirement as the input to the method is passed dynamically using TextInput.

~Jegan

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking two things:

1. How to list all of the properties/methods of a UIComponent.
2. How to list all of the UIComponents in the Flex SDK.

The first one can be done with `describeType()`.  Given that *the method is passed dynamically using TextInput*, you need to just include all of the UIComponents into the SWF.  You can do that with the following `include` statement for each component in the SDK (this example is with the Button):

`include mx.controls.Button; Button;`.

Then you can do something like this:

```
var className:String = myTextArea.text; // mx.controls::Button or mx.controls.Button
var clazz:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(className);
var methods:Array = getMethods(clazz);
var properties:Array = getProperties(clazz); // write a similar method for accessors and variables

/**
 *  Returns a list of methods for the class.
 * Pass in the superclass depth for how many classes
 * you want this to return (class tree).  If it's -1, it will return the whole method list
 */
public static function getMethods(target:Object, superclassDepth:int = -1, keepGeneratedMethods:Boolean = false):Array
{
 var description:XML = DescribeTypeCache.describeType(target).typeDescription;
 var hierarchy:Array = getHierarchy(target);
 var methodList:XMLList = description..method;
 methodList += description.factory..method; // factory is required if target is Class
 var methodName:String
 var methods:Array = [];
 var declaredBy:String;
 var methodXML:XML;
 var i:int = 0;
 var n:int = methodList.length();
 for (i; i < n; i++)
 {
  methodXML = methodList[i];
  declaredBy = methodXML.@declaredBy;
  methodName = methodXML.@name;
  // we break because the xml list is orded hierarchically by class!
  if (superclassDepth != -1 && hierarchy.indexOf(declaredBy) >= superclassDepth)
   break;
  // ignore methods that start with underscore:
  if (methodName.charAt(0) == "_" && !keepGeneratedMethods)
   continue;
  methods.push(methodName);
 }
 // sort the method list, so there's some kind of order to the report:
 methods.sort(Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
 return methods;
}
```

The second one, listing the UIComponents in the SDK, is a bit more complex because there's no stable list of components in the SDK (depends on version, etc.).  What you *can* do, however, is get a list of every class included in the swf.  You do this by generating a [Link Report](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_4.html) (which is used for helping out modules), which is just a compiler argument:

`-link-report=my_report.xml`

Then you can figure out a way to find the unique xml nodes in that file, and which ones extend UIComponent.  I use ruby and the [nokogiri xml parser for ruby](http://nokogiri.org/) to do that.  There is also a neat [AIR app to visualize the Link Report](http://www.kahunaburger.com/2008/03/08/air-link-report-visualizer/).

If you're doing the first case, that method should get you started on listing all properties/methods of a UIComponent.  If you're doing the second, that will give you a list of all UIComponents included in the swf.

Let me know if that helps,
Lance

Comment: The above code is not working for me when i input "Button" in the TextArea control. The error message that i am getting is "ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Button is not defined." Please let me know if there is anything wrong that i did.

Comment: Save yourself some imports: `import mx.controls.*`

Comment: that reference error is because the Button is not included in the swf. importing it alone with `import mx.controls.*;` won't include it in the swf. you need to either create a variable for it: `public var uselessButtonVariable:Button;`, or do that import thing I showed above: `import mx.controls.Button; Button;`.  Try that and it should work.

Comment: here is an example of an "imports" class the flex sdk uses: http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/FrameworkClasses.as

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do anything with the data, other than displaying it? If not, it might be easiest to pull up the right page from Adobe's online API docs.